# Select2 Fill Drop down with ajax Web Method not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, jquery-select2

CSS
User select2  version Select2-4.0.13
and bootstrap4

```
   <link href="Styles/Select2-4.0.13/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <link href="Styles/Select2-4.0.13/select2-bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

ASPX
Created Dropdown list Name with class js-data-example-ajax

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" class="js-data-example-ajax" style="width: 300px">
    </asp:DropDownList>
</form>
```

JAVA SCRIPT
loaded data to select2 dropdown using ajax web method call in document ready method
but its raising error and not working properly

```
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.4.1/jquery-3.4.1.min.css" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/Select2-4.0.13/select2.full.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.js-data-example-ajax').select2({
                theme: 'bootstrap4',
                minimumInputLength: 1,
                containerCssClass: ':all:',
                allowClear: true,
                ajax: {
                    url: 'WebForm1.aspx/getsource',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    //type: "POST",
                    params: {
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                    },
                    data: function (params) {
                        var query = {
                            q: params.term,
                            page: params.page
                        }
                        return query;
                    },
                    processResults: function (data, params) {
                        params.page = params.page || 1;
                        data = jQuery.map(data.results, function (obj) {
                            obj.id = obj.id;
                            obj.text = obj.text;
                            return obj;
                        });
                        return {
                            results: data,
                            pagination: {
                                more: params.page * 30 < 4//total records
                            }
                        };
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log("SUCCESS: ", data);
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        console.log("ERROR: ", data);
                    },
                    cache: true
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

.CS File
Created Method as web method to load data to dropdown list with select2

```
  [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public static string getsource(string q, int page)
        {
            Select2ModelMain obj = new Select2ModelMain();
            obj.results = new List<SelectResult>();

            SelectResult objdata1 = new SelectResult();
            objdata1.id = 1;
            objdata1.text = "INDIA";
            obj.results.Add(objdata1);

            objdata1 = new SelectResult();
            objdata1.id = 2;
            objdata1.text = "AMERICA";
            obj.results.Add(objdata1);

            objdata1 = new SelectResult();
            objdata1.id = 3;
            objdata1.text = "CHINA";
            obj.results.Add(objdata1);

            objdata1 = new SelectResult();
            objdata1.id = 4;
            objdata1.text = "SRILANKA";
            obj.results.Add(objdata1);

            obj.pagination = new SelectPage();
            obj.pagination.more = "true";

            if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(q) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(q)))
            {
                obj.results = obj.results.Where(x => x.text.ToLower().StartsWith(q.ToLower())).ToList();
            }
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string test = serializer.Serialize(obj);
            return test;
        }

        public class Select2ModelMain
        {
            public List<SelectResult> results { get; set; }
            public SelectPage pagination { get; set; }
        }

        public class SelectResult
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string text { get; set; }
            public string disabled { get; set; }
        }

        public class SelectPage
        {
            public string more { get; set; }
        }
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQbX4.png)

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1:
On Select2ModelMain change

```
public List<SelectResult> results { get; set; }
```

to (I'm having an issue on if it is name results)

```
public List<SelectResult> items { get; set; }
```

Step 2:

Try this javascript as an initial to check if it's working.
Note: Make sure that the action method is 'POST' instead of 'GET' i'm not sure what is the issue on if GET for select2 for a normal ajax call it works.

> **Side Note:**
> When using GET on normal ajax request this should be set to UseHttpGet = true
> `[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = true)]`

[For other options when using select2 remote query](https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.js-data-example-ajax').select2({
            ajax: {
                url: 'TestSelect2Page.aspx/getsource',
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                delay: 250,
                data: function (params) {

                    var search = '';

                    if (params.term !== undefined) {
                        search = params.term;
                    }

                    return "{'q': '" + search + "'}";
                },
                processResults: function (data) {
                    var items = JSON.parse(data.d).items

                    if (items == null) {
                        return null;
                    }

                    return {
                        results: items
                    };
                }
            },
            placeholder: 'Search here',
            minimumInputLength: 1
        });
    });
```

**OUTPUT 1:** 
[image: Output 1]

**OUTPUT 2:** 
[image]

I hope this helps. Happy coding.

Comment: Thank you so much its working...
 
but we are facing another issue please check my answer...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much its working...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4izYq.png)
but we are facing another issue

i.e. selected event changed OnSelectedIndexChanged is not working

so we added another line "<asp:ListItem Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>"

after this it fires OnSelectedIndexChanged  but its not showing selected Item
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjLsb.png)
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAUrF.png)

```
 <asp:Label ID="LblItemName" runat="server" Style="font-weight: bold;" Text="Product Name"></asp:Label>
                                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="txtItemName" data-width="100%" CssClass="select2-single input-sm w-100"
                                    AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="txtItemName_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                    <asp:ListItem Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Do you really need to use DropDownList and DataGridView? Or, it's ok for you to use <select> and <table>? The problem is that once your DropDown became a select2 control the functionality of its server side events will no longer work instantly. There are some ways/hacks etc. but it will make the main goal complicated.